# Rust Map Syntax Explanation Needed

Tags: dictionary, rust, substrate

recently started learning Rust and I am having some problems with syntax.
Can anyone explain to me this line:

```
// Stores all the kitties, key is the kitty id / index

pub Kitties get(fn kitties): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u32 => Option<Kitty>;
```

So we're creating here public Kitties(variable) that accepts some function.
Kitties is of a type map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u32 which returns Option

map hasher? Also couldn't find hasher in documentation.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Rust syntax, where did this come from?

Comment: This is definitely not valid Rust. It looks like an *attempt* at valid Rust, so you probably haven't misidentified the language, but it certainly won't work as is.

Comment: It's from substrate(https://substrate.dev/recipes/storage-maps.html)

Comment: That looks like it's happening inside a macro, which basically means anything goes. You'll have to read the docs on [that particular macro](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html) to figure out what's up.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'd recommend posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link you posted in the comments, the code snippet is part of a larger snippet that looks something like

```
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as SimpleMap {
        SimpleMap get(fn simple_map): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::AccountId => u32;
    }
}
```

The `decl_storage!` call is a macro (macro calls are always ended in an exclamation point, like `vec!` or `println!`), which in essence means it can do whatever it wants with the stuff that follows it. In particular, the things inside the outer braces needn't be valid Rust, as `decl_storage!` can transform the contents freely.

My guess (at a quick Google search) is that `decl_storage!` refers to [this macro](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html), so you'll have to refer to its documentation to see what it expects.

Answer (score 2):

This is a macro rule. Not origin Rust syntax.

Check this out: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0/frame_support/macro.decl_storage.html

If you want to learn more about Map storage type in substrate check this, it also explains what hasher is:
https://substrate.dev/recipes/storage-maps.html